# Deciding who was the better meteorologist

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Each night different meteorologists give us the probability that it
will rain the next day. To judge how well these people predict, we
will score each of them as follows: If a meteorologist says that it will
rain with probability $p$, then he or she will receive a score of

$1 - (1 - p)^2$
if it does rain

$1 - p^2$
if it does not rain.

We will then keep tracks of scores over a certain time span and
conclude that the meteorologist with the highest average is the best
predictor of weather. Suppose now that a given meteorologist is
aware of this and wants to maximize his or her expected score. If
this person truly believes that it will rain tomorrow with probability
$p^*$
, what is the value of $p$ should he or she assert so as to maximize
the expected score ?

---

Here is the solution:

Let $X$ be the expected score. Let $x$ be the probability asserted by the meteorologist. Then

$$E(X)=p^*(1 - (1 - x)^2)+ (1-p^*)(1 - x^2)$$

Then maximizing the function we obtain $x=p^*$.

---

This question has left me quite confused on one hand we are told that the final average score will be considered to decide who the better meteorologist was. Then at the end of the question we are asked to maximize the expected score.

Does this question make sense? How would one explain this to a confused student? Help!

Comment: There are two actors in this problem: the person assigning scores (who is not a meteorologist) and a meteorologist who wants a high score. Analogously, if you are a student, your professor will assign you a grade. The professor (presumably) wants your grade to represent how well you mastered the material, but _you_ (quite possibly) want to maximize your grade.

Comment: And to understand the motivation of the question, think of it as something your professor is asking themselves -- have I designed this test in such a way that my students's answers will reflect their true beliefs, or can they do better by answering strategically?